# Population data xquery

Tags: xquery

For the XML data below I am trying to get the output shown here: I.e I want to see the names of the countries having a population greater than 20000 , with the conditions that the number of cities displayed should only be for those with a population more than 3500. Also, For some countries the city is within a province.

---

```
<result>
  <country name="B">
    <num_cities>3</num_cities>
  </country>
  <country name="C">
    <num_cities>2</num_cities>
  </country>
</result>
```

---------------------------This is the XML data----------------------

```
<country id="1" name="A" population="12000">
   <name>A</name>
   <city id="c1" country="1">
      <name>T1</name>
      <population>5000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c2" country="1">
      <name>T2</name>
      <population>3000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c3" country="1">
      <name>T3</name>
      <population>4000</population>
   </city>
</country>
<country id="3" name="B" population="80000">
   <name>B</name>
   <city id="c4" country="2">
      <name>T4</name>
      <population>6000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c5" country="2">
      <name>T5</name>
      <population>2000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c6" country="2">
      <name>T6</name>
      <population>60000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c7" country="2">
      <name>T7</name>
      <population>12000</population>
   </city>
</country>
<country id="3" name="C" population="68000">
   <name>C</name>
   <province>P1</province>
   <city id="c8" country="3">
      <name>T8</name>
      <population>51000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c9" country="3">
      <name>T9</name>
      <population>3000</population>
   </city>
   <city id="c10" country="3">
      <name>T10</name>
      <population>14000</population>
   </city>
</country>
```

---

I wrote this xquery but i don't know how to exclude the cities having a population > 3500. I might not have written to code correctly either...Please assist.

```
for $c in doc("abc")//country
let $city:= count($c/city/name)
let $citypr:= count($c/province/city/name)
where $c/@population>1000000
return
<result>
<country name='{data($c/name) }'></country>
 <num_of_cities>
 {
 if (exists ($c/city/name)) then
 $city
 else
 $citypr
}
 </num_of_cities>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- Don't bother with `where` clauses where you can filter down earlier, in a specifier retrieving your content.
- If you want to have only one `<result>`, rather than one per datum, you need to start it **before** the FLWOR expression; whatever you 'return' will be returned once per item.

This is an example of something closer:

```
<result>{
  for $large-country in doc("abc")//country[@population > 20000]
  let $large-cities := $country/city[population > 3500]
  return
    <country name="{$large-country/@name}">
      <num_cities>{count($large-cities)}</num_cities>
    </country>
}</result>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how do I also include the countries that have cities inside provinces. I must check and display according, for instance country 3's cities are inside a province.

Comment: I think I got what I was looking for, thank you so much for your kind assistance.<result>{
  for $large-country in doc("abc")//country[@population > 20000]
  let $large-cities := $large-country/city[population > 3500]
  let $large-citiesp := $large-country/province/city[population > 3500]
  return
    <country name="{$large-country/@name}">
    <num_cities>{
 if (exists ($large-country/city/name)) then
 count($large-cities)
 else
 count($large-citiesp)
}
 
   </num_cities>
    </country>
}</result>